# Running a Full Node through VPN?

Tags: full-node

My ISP has blocked port 8333, due to the gigs of inbound traffic I incurred running a full node. Consequently, I would like to run a full node through VPN (specifically, OpenVPN with an OpenVPN provider).

Would I need to have the VPN forward port 8333?

Comment: You can try running `bitcoind -port=<another-port>` but I imagine they'll just block that port as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, incoming connections must be allowed through port 8333. If your VPN provider allows port-forwarding, it should be configurable in your account settings.

See: https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#network-configuration